# Objective C improve CIImage filter speed

Tags: objective-c, performance, opencv, core-graphics, core-image

I wrote the following code to apply a Sepia filter to an image:

```
- (void)applySepiaFilter {
    // Set previous image
    NSData *buffer = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: self.mainImage.image];
    [_images push:[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: buffer]];


    UIImage* u = self.mainImage.image;
    CIImage *image = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:u.CGImage];
    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISepiaTone"
                                  keysAndValues: kCIInputImageKey, image,
                        @"inputIntensity", @0.8, nil];
    CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];
    self.mainImage.image = [self imageFromCIImage:outputImage];
}

- (UIImage *)imageFromCIImage:(CIImage *)ciImage {
    CIContext *ciContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef cgImage = [ciContext createCGImage:ciImage fromRect:[ciImage extent]];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
    return image;
}
```

When I run this code it seems to lag for 1-2 seconds. I heard that core image is faster than core graphics but I am unimpressed with the rendering time. I was wondering if this would be faster processing in CoreGraphics or even OpenCV(which is being used elsewhere in the project)? If not is there any way I can optimize this code to run faster?

Comment: Have you used Instruments to find out what's actually slow here?

Comment: @zneak What instruments would those be?

Comment: Off my head, something like "Time Profiler".

Answer (score 10):

I can almost guarantee it will be slower in Core Graphics than using Core Image, depending on the size of the image. If the image is small, Core Graphics may be fine, but if you are doing a lot of processing, it will be much slower than rendering using the GPU.

Core Image is very fast, however, you have to be very conscious of what is going on. Most of the performance hit with Core Image is due to setting up of the context, and copying images to/from Core Image. In addition to just copying bytes, Core Image may be converting between image formats as well.

Your code is doing the following every time:

- Creating a CIContext. (slow)
- Taking bytes from a CGImage and creating a CIImage.
- Copying image data to GPU (slow).
- Processing Sepia filter (fast).
- Copying result image back to CGImage. (slow)

This is not a recipe for peak performance. Bytes from CGImage will typically live in CPU memory, but Core Image wants to use the GPU for its processing.

An excellent reference for performance considerations are provided in [Getting the Best Performance](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_performance/ci_performance.html) documentation for Core Image:

> - Don’t create a CIContext object every time you render.
>     Contexts store a lot of state information; it’s more efficient to reuse them.
> - Evaluate whether you app needs color management. Don’t use it unless you need it. See Does Your App Need Color Management?.
> - Avoid Core Animation animations while rendering CIImage objects with a GPU context.
>     If you need to use both simultaneously, you can set up both to use the CPU.
> - Make sure images don’t exceed CPU and GPU limits. (iOS)
> - Use smaller images when possible.
>     Performance scales with the number of output pixels. You can have Core Image render into a smaller view, texture, or framebuffer. Allow Core Animation to upscale to display size.
> - Use Core Graphics or Image I/O functions to crop or downsample, such as the functions CGImageCreateWithImageInRect or CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex.
> - The UIImageView class works best with static images.
>     If your app needs to get the best performance, use lower-level APIs.
> - Avoid unnecessary texture transfers between the CPU and GPU.
>     Render to a rectangle that is the same size as the source image before applying a contents scale factor.
> - Consider using simpler filters that can produce results similar to algorithmic filters.
>     For example, CIColorCube can produce output similar to CISepiaTone, and do so more efficiently.
> - Take advantage of the support for YUV image in iOS 6.0 and later.

If you demand real-time processing performance, you will want to use an OpenGL view that CoreImage can render its output to, and read your image bytes directly into the GPU instead of pulling it from a CGImage. Using a `GLKView`, and overriding `drawRect:` is a fairly simple solution to get a view that Core Image can render directly to. Keeping data on the GPU is the best way to get peak performance out of Core Image.

Try to reuse as much as possible. Keep a `CIContext` around for subsequent renders (like the doc says). If you end up using an OpenGL view, these are also things you may want to re-use as much as possible.

You may also be able to get better performance by using software rendering. Software rendering would avoid a copy to/from GPU. `[CIContext contextWithOptions:@{kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer: @(YES)}]` However, this will have performance limitations in the actual render, since the CPU render is usually slower than a GPU render.

So, you can choose your level of difficulty to get maximum performance. The best performance can be more challenging, but a few tweaks may get you to "acceptable" performance for your use case.